# double inclusion of same jQuery plungin conflict issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fancybox

I created a wordpress plugin (say P1 ) in which I used fancybox (a jquery plugin). I included its js using wordpress's wp_enqueue_script() function.

But, on my client wordpress blog, he is using some other wordpress plugin, one of them (say P2) also use fancybox.

When both these P1 and P2 are active, fancybox js loads 2 time one from P1 and another from P2. And due to this it gives error

> loading is undefined (on line 36)

can I

1. prevent fancybox to load 2 or more times from my wordpress plugin
2. or handle this js error

prevent

Comment: You need to prevent this loading twice in the page if at all possible, can you do that from the wordpress side?  Or include your script last and it check if the plugin's already loaded when doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can prevent loading your script twice from your side (wordpress side) if you have control over it.

You can probably use the typeOf operator to see if a particular fancybox has already loaded and if yes you do not include it twice.

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is your friend! Providing the other plugin is using [the correct technique for loading JavaScript](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html), you can simply queue the same handle in your plugin.

That way, Fancybox will only ever load once, regardless if both plugins are queueing it.

- [The Right Way of Adding JavaScript in WordPress](http://zacklive.com/the-right-way-of-adding-javascript-to-wordpress/1038/)
- [Best practice for adding JavaScript to WordPress plugins](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/best-practice-for-adding-javascript-code-to-wordpress-plugin)
- [How to load JavaScript like a WordPress master](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)
- [And many more](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress+loading+javascript+the+right+way)!